# Help needed with math/bignum challenge

Tags: c, math, gmp

I'm struggling with the following bit of code(/challenge) and I was wondering what would be the best way to solve it.

#### Pseudo(-like) code

If I understand the code correctly it does:

```
var val = 1
foreach (char in firstargument):
  val = val * ((ascii)char + 27137)

if (val == 92156295871308407838808214521283596197005567493826981266515267734732800)
  print "correct"
else
  print "incorrect"
```

Where 'firstargument' is an argument passed to the program like: ./program 123456...

#### Actual code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mpz_t val, mul, cmpval;
    char str[513];
    int n = 0;

    mpz_init(val);
    mpz_set_ui(val, 1);
    mpz_init(mul);
    mpz_init(cmpval);
    mpz_set_str(cmpval, "92156295871308407838808214521283596197005567493826981266515267734732800", 10);

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("%s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    strncpy(str, argv[1], 512);

    for (n = 0; n < strlen(str); n++)
    {
        mpz_set_ui(mul, (unsigned long)(str[n] + 27137));
        mpz_mul(val, val, mul);
    }

    if (!(n = mpz_cmp(val, cmpval)))
    {
        printf("correct.\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("incorrect.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The solution is 'hfesbbirroooooay'.

Comment: @KennyTM: Hah thanks, sounds like you have seen this one before? I'll try if I can figure it out myself tho with the help of Will A's answer. The solution itself is not that important to me, more the part on how to get there.

Comment: No. It is just similar to Will's answer. Notice that the solution is not unique.

Comment: The solution is unique up to the order of the letters, so it is an anagram puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this from the point-of-view that the large number must be divisible by `((ascii)theVeryLastChar + 27137)` - and try to figure out what this last char is - and then divide by it and work it for the 'the second from last char' etc.

Comment: +1 for figuring out what the question was as well as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little Prolog program to compute the solutions, with the letters with lower ASCII codes first.

```
solve(A) :-
    number_anagram(92156295871308407838808214521283596197005567493826981266515267734732800, L),
    atom_codes(A,L).

number_anagram(N, L) :-
    number_anagram(N, 32, L).

number_anagram(1, 126, []).
number_anagram(N, C, [C|R]) :-
    N > 1,
    F is C + 27137,
    N mod F =:= 0,
    N1 is N / F,
    number_anagram(N1, C, R).
number_anagram(N, C, L) :-
    C < 126,
    C1 is C + 1,
    number_anagram(N, C1, L).
```

It turns out there is only one solution:

```
$ swipl
```

[...]

```
?- ['number-anagram.pl'].
% number-anagram.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 1,636 bytes
true.

?- solve(A).
A = abbefhiooooorrsy ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is also known as the chinese remainder theorem/problem.
The diogenes algorithm is the solution.